# how does the compiler write values to the second value of the pair in this construct?

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair

```
map<int,int> a;
pair<std::map<int,int>::iterator ,bool> f;
f=(a.insert({0,0}));
cout<<f.second;
```

why is it outputting 1?

it always outputs 1 for any values in the pair

Comment: If you try to insert the same item twice it'll be 0. https://godbolt.org/z/xbree4q6q

Comment: `std::cout << true;` prints 1 (on most systems)

Comment: Please learn to inspect documentation, [it is described there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert#Return_value)! Reading documentation is one of most important skills in code development.

Comment: @Caleth this is configurable see [std::boolalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because the `bool` `f.second` tells you if `insert` inserted the `pair<int,int>` into the map. `1` means that it *did* insert it.

`bool`s are normally printed as either `0` (`false`) or `1` (`true`). You can use the I/O manipulator `std::boolalpha` to make it print `true` or `false` instead.

> it always outputs 1 for any values in the pair

No. If you try to insert a `pair` with a *Key* value that already exists in the `map<int,int>` it will return a `pair<std::map<int,int>::iterator ,bool>` where the `bool` is `false` and the iterator will point at the existing element in the `map<int,int>`.